# copiar en el portapapeles el resultado Python

Tags: python

```
saludar = "hola buenos días,"
preguntar = " como esta"

print( saludar + preguntar)
```

¿Cómo hacer que el computador copie el `print` que resulta? Como si se copiara con el <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, pero sin necesita de este que Python mismo lo haga

Comment: Has intentado algo, has investigado?

Comment: Instala pyperclip: `pip install pyperclip`, y utiliza `pyperclip.copy`